# Storing events payload in a relational way but they're coming in a non-guaranteed order

Tags: postgresql, stripe-payments, relational-database

## Context

I've got an app requiring people to pay using Stripe.

Stripe has a short timeout to handle its webhook calls so the stack we came up with is the following:

[image]

- **Stripe** as a 3rd party provider for payments
- **AWS API Gateway**: Endpoint that is the webhook that Stripe is going to call when new events happen
- **AWS SQS Queue**: When the API Gateway receives an event, it puts it into the SQS Queue and tells Stripe *(for the webhook call)* that everything was taken into account so that Stripe doesn't consider this event as failed
- "**Authorization Service**" *(built by us)* which listens to our SQS Queue and saves messages in a DB

We can then query the Authorization Service to know if a user has paid or not.

## What we're trying to achieve

While this has been working well so far, we'd like to change how we handle the DB on the Authorization Service. We built it in a non relational way because Stripe doesn't guarantee the order of events sent to the webhook (makes sense because they can be retried as well) and because we wanted to keep all the events to have history for traceability.

We're about to add more features on that Authorization Service and manipulate more data. Therefore we'd like to change it to be taking advantage of the relational approach of PostgreSQL and have proper foreign keys. For example, we save the products, the users and the subscriptions. If an event about a subscription comes in referencing a product and a user but none of these have been received so far, in the new architecture it'd fail because the foreign key check wouldn't accept that.

I'm trying to wrap my head around how we could:

- Take advantage of a relational DB
- Keep history for traceability

The challenge being of course events coming out of order in a relational DB.

## Option I'm thinking of

When we receive a message from the SQS queue, we'd try to save it in the database. If it fails because of an issue happening on a primary key, we create a local queue *(and by local queue I'm not talking about an SQS like queue, just a simple array to maintain orders of events to retry and a retry happening regularly)* for this event to be retried soon. Meanwhile, other events may be saved correctly and when the first one is being retried, it shall succeed. To make sure we don't lose events, while an event is put in our local queue to be retried, we'd not signal to SQS that the message has been taken into account yet. This way if the server crashes or is shutdown while the local queue wasn't proceeded yet, it'd be retried as expected on the next start.

A potential downside of this would be that we're going to be retrying inserting events again and again for a bit, it may take some time user side to see some actions taken into account. That said, we can probably mitigate this by retrying quite often (every seconds?). I don't think the local queue should end up being really big but I could be wrong. I also wonder if in some cases, we could be in a state where the retry order would never settle but I don't think so (?).

## How would you approach this?

Have you ever encountered such a thing? How did you solve it? Surely that's pretty classic but even after some research I'm still unclear as to what's my best option for this.

Comment: Why don't you listen to SQS too?

Comment: When there is a data insertion failure due to a foreign key mismatch, why not using Stripe APi in order to fetch that object by id and insert it too. After inserting all related objects, insert the event.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, but I do listen from SQS. I then put the data received from the events in SQS queue into my DB

Comment: @os4m37 that could be an option indeed. The only thing that annoys me there is that Stripe is very clear about the fact that the API is super limited on purpose because they don't want the API to be abused and they want people to use webhooks (which makes sense from their POV right? They'll broadcast an event once instead of having many requests to poll for it). But I'm a little afraid that one day we may hit the rate limitation. That's the only downside I can think of with this solution

Comment: What is the rate limitation - does it come from stripe? What percentage are you using at the moment?

Comment: Umh, I remember looking at the rate limiting on Stripe and they used to be more vague about it without giving real numbers. That said, now it looks like they're giving real numbers and it isn't as bad as one could've thought based on the description they had earlier: https://stripe.com/docs/rate-limits

Comment: I guess there's also a risk of "cascading" when doing this and instead of creating a pool of events to try to apply them in order we'd end up querying Stripe but what if you've got dependencies of dependencies of dependencies. Could be even worst when there's a one to many relationship. Again, not sure this would happen in practice but trying to anticipate anything that could go wrong as it's quite a critical part of our stack

Comment: The other option I can think of that wouldn’t cost too much traffic would be to wait and arrange events in order on the endpoint before logging it in the DB. After all, if you’re only working with Subscriptions, then you know what chain of events trigger from both Sub creation and updates. You can queue them in your handler without going back and forth with your DB. That said if your Stripe integration is more diverse, this try catch might be safer

Comment: Keep the current design without explicite referencial integrity and define views with a *status* column for each FK, showing if the PK exists or not.

Comment: "The challenge being of course events coming out of order in a relational DB." Then your DB records need a timestamp, possibly two: transaction time (when the subscriber clicked OK in their ap); processed time (when the DB received a whole valid transaction sufficient to satisfy the FKs). I'd then put an `ON INSERT` trigger to validate the key relationships, rather than declaring a FK. (Because SQL FKs aren't very clever.)